# Create Circle Image View IOS issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, custom-view

I want to create a Circle image view for my profile avatar. I have tried this:-

```
   class CircleImageView: UIImageView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code

        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = min(rect.width/2 , rect.height/2)
        clipsToBounds = true


    }
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint in the layer.masksToBounds line and check the size and height of the rect.

Comment: And add borderWidth borderColor properties to get a visual representation of resulted view.

Comment: Is your image's width equal to it's height?

Comment: make sure your "rect" size is a square, i.e. width and height should be same

Comment: try this ..`yourImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * (yourImageView?.bounds.size.width)!`

Comment: @Avinash kumawat - First make sure your image frame should be square i.e.width and height should be same and then replace min(rect.width/2 , rect.height/2) with rect.frame.size.height/2 Hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

An `extension` will be great to set corner or do round image:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setRadius(radius: CGFloat? = nil) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius ?? self.frame.width / 2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
imgview.setRadius(radius: 10)
imgview.setRadius() //default frame.width/2
```

Comment: It is not wrong at all to extend the UIImageView, but the main purpose of subclassing UIImageView is to let setRadius() works automatically when creating a new instance with any extra method calling

Answer (score 1):

Draw function is for drawing not changing layer.

Use layoutSubviews

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = min(self.frame.width/2 , self.frame.height/2)
        clipsToBounds = true

}
```

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() is a UIViewController method but not a UIView.

Comment: @AhmadF tnx i fixed the answer

Comment: Np, it is not fixed yet :) I highly recommend to test your answer on a playground before you even post it.

Comment: how so @AhmadF . changed viewDidLayoutSubviews to layoutSubviews :-?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the code in the wrong place, [drawRect:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect) is not really the right method to do such a functionality for editing the layer, you can achive this by:

Editing the layer when [init(frame:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622488-init) the imageView (also, adding the same functionality in [init(coder:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding/1416145-init) because it should work for both approaches: programmatically and via storyboard):

```
class CircleImageView: UIImageView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupCircleLayer()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setupCircleLayer()
    }

    private func setupCircleLayer() {
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = min(frame.width/2 , frame.height/2)
        clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

---

Or as @Mohammadalijf suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115861/5501940) by overriding [layoutSubviews()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) method:

```
class CircleImageView: UIImageView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = min(frame.width/2 , frame.height/2)
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

It does the desired fucntionality that you are asking for, but note that:

> Subclasses can override this method as needed to perform more precise
>   layout of their subviews. **You should override this method *only* if the
>   autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not
>   offer the behavior you want**. You can use your implementation to set
>   the frame rectangles of your subviews directly.

i.e, it is related to updating the layout of the view, check the documentation for more information; That's why I prefer to do it in the `init` methods.

Comment: In init function autolayout didnt layout the view so the width of the frame will be 0 if created in storyboard. But works fine if you init the view programmatically with frame

Comment: @Mohammadalijf my bad :) I forgot about this point, now it should work fine, thanks for the comment